# Error when trying to load any entry from cloud server

Tags: cloud

I got following error message when displaying or tracing a proxy:

No server entry found with ID 2620cae8-b15f-4c69-bd81-b4bd18379e10

My Apigee cloud account is jamesxu.!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give it another try and let us know? This should be working fine now.

Thanks,
Archendra